# Multi level SQL filtering for most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have gone over selecting the most recent data from the database but I need to expand the query now.  What I have so far is

```
from tblUserProperties inner join  
(   select TOP(1) id from tblUserProperties     
        where updated=( 
        Select max(updated) from tblUserProperties 
    ) 
) as X  
on tblUserProperties.id=X.id  
where collector='gs'
```

which gives me a result set of

```
propertyName    propertyValue
Credits             176
```

The data that I am drawing from is

```
id  collectorId collector   propertyName    propertyValue   updated
293 183 gs                      lastName                My                                              2020-03-17 19:29:30.000
294 183 gs                      firstName               Name                                                2020-04-17 19:29:30.000
295 183 gs                      client                  0                                                   2020-03-19 19:29:30.000
296 183 gs                      notes                   TEST - Updated                                      2020-02-17 19:29:30.000
297 183 gs                      branch                  1                                                   2019-09-17 19:29:30.000
298 183 gs                      EmployeeNumber          1111                                                2020-03-17 19:29:30.000
299 183 gs                      SMSCredits              111                                                 2020-04-14 06:51:30.000
300 183 gs                      EmployeeAccess          11111                                               2020-03-17 19:29:30.000
301 183 gs                      phoneNumber             888-888-8888                                        2019-11-17 19:29:30.000
302 183 gs                      Credits                 111                                                 2020-04-14 06:51:30.000
```

This is data for the user 'gsutton'.  Other users have different data with different dates.  What I am looking to get is the most current update of each distinct value.  Sadly I have no idea how to modify my query to accomplish this, and need the help of you SQL experts.

****Update****

Expected Output:

```
propertyName    propertyValue         updated
lastName                My            3/17/2020
firstName               Name          3/17/2020
client                  0             3/17/2020
notes                   TEST          3/17/2020
branch                  1             3/17/2020
EmployeeNumber          1111          3/17/2020
EmployeeAccess          11111         3/17/2020
phoneNumber             888-111-1111  3/17/2020
Credits                 111           4/14/2020
```

Notice that there is now only 1 Credits Column, the one with the most recent date, rather than 2 in the sample data.

Comment: Is date available in your table?

Comment: It's the "updated" column

Comment: which distinct value are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. It will give you last updated value where collector was gs.

```
select  
    propertyName,
    propertyValue
from
(
    select
        propertyName,
        propertyValue,
        collector,
        row_number() over (partition by propertyValue order by updated desc) as lastupdated
    from tblUserProperties
) val
where collector = 'gs'
and lastupdated = 1
```

If you have same collector throughout table then you do not need to do `partition by collectorId` in `row_nubmer()` function.

Comment: You don't take the `updated` date into account for _each_ individual `propertyName`. My SWAG is that the OP may have cases where the may be several occurrences of one property, e.g. `'notes'`, and only wants the most recent. Of course they didn't bother with that in their sample data.

Comment: This query gives the same results as my original.  It is taking only the first result of the potential values.

Comment: @Geoff could you please provide your expected output?

Comment: @zealous That is a definite step in the right direction.  If you look at the data you will see that there are a few different dates.  This is giving me everything with the most recent date.  Unfortunately what I need is the most recent property and value for each property.  Would there be a way to filter by DISTINCT updated for this user in order to get all the values required using an inner join?

Comment: @Geoff this is confusin, `property and value for each property`. Also if you can put your expected output would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give us the table structure; sample data; and desired result.

Based on what I think you want (not sure if this is correct due to above comment)

```
select DISTINCT 
,collectorId 
,collector
,LAST_VALUE(propertyName) OVER (PARTITION BY collectorid,collector ORDER BY updated asc) as LastUpdatedPropertyName
,LAST_VALUE(propertyValue) OVER (PARTITION BY collectorid,collector ORDER BY updated asc)  as LastUpdatedPropertyValue
,LAST_VALUE(updated) OVER (PARTITION BY collectorid, collector ORDER BY updated asc)  as LastUpdatedDate
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: All the table structure and sample data are in the question.  And sadly I am running SQL Server 2008 - LAST_VALUE won't work :(

Comment: Assuming that the tblUserProperties has the header you provided (id  collectorId collector   propertyName    propertyValue   updated) . Please give us more sample data and a snapshot of the results that you expect. I am sure somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: @zealous - I updated the question with slightly changed data - different dates - as well as a desired result from the query.  The necessary fields are propertyName and propertyValue with a single value for each property.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was pulling from C# I used a combination of queries and LiNQ to get the data I wanted.  I used 2 simple select queries then filtered them with LiNQ as below.

```
            var query = "Select id, propertyName, propertyValue, updated " +
                "from tblUserProperties where collector='{0}'";

            query = string.Format(query, user);
            DataTable dt = DataFunctions.RunQuery(query, QUERYTYPES.SELECT, "MCAIntranet");

            query = "Select distinct propertyName " +
                "from tblUserProperties where collector='{0}'";

            query = string.Format(query, user);
            DataTable dt2 = DataFunctions.RunQuery(query, QUERYTYPES.SELECT, "dbName");


            //the SMS Credits item is added as a second row
            //so loop through all potential value rows for user
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
            {
               var name = dr["propertyName"].ToString().Trim();

                try
                {
                    var tmp = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              where row.Field<string>("propertyName").Trim() == name
                              orderby row.Field<DateTime>("updated") descending
                              select row).FirstOrDefault();
    ...
```

This worked successfully with extensive testing.  It's not an SQL solution but it did provide the data I needed.